# Llenar base de datos local en Android con registros en Firebase

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

Tengo una aplicación `Android` con una conexión a `Firebase` para el modelo de datos.

Al iniciar la aplicación, debo acceder a los datos, para ello se usa un `addValueEventListener`, lo que hace es escuchar si se hacen cambios en `Firebase` para representarlos en la aplicación.

Mi problema es que no se como hacer que escuche durante todo el momento en la aplicación, si lo pongo en un `activity`, cuando cambio a otro `activity`, pues deja de escuchar y ese no es el chiste. Intenté hacerlo con un `BroadcastReciever` pero los datos se obtienen en desorden y cuando los ingreso en la base de datos local, se genera un `NullPointerException` dado que se insertan datos de tablas que requieren la llave de otro registro que aún no se ha ingresado

Comment: Crea un servicio en segundo plano que se mantenga escuchando.

Comment: Bienvenido Yeison, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas, actualmente se define como "demasiada amplia". También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: parece que es mas un problema de sincronizacion y como usas los datos. Podrías comentar en detalles que es lo que intentas hacer e incluir el código para ver que estas haciendo hoy?

Comment: ya se cual es el problema, muchas gracias, les comento, Firebase es una plataforma de google para manejo de datos en tiempo real, o sea que cada cambio que se haga en la base, se ve reflejado en todos los dispositivos conectados, yo necesito es una base de datos accedida desde un sitio web y muchos dispositivos móviles, y la base de datos debo descargarla completa en los dispositivos, por lo tanto FB no me sirve para ese propósito; por otro lado, FB usa listenners para saber cuando se hacen cambios y descargarlos si no, no obtengo mi base de datos y por eso siempre me generaba punteros a null.